# Is skin friction also pressure drag looking at microscopic level?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag

Roughness in boudary layer is taller than height of air which is not moving ,feel oncoming airflow in boudary layer, at front side must be high pressure at rear low pressure etc,so net force is to the right,this is classical pressure drag for roughness "object"...

If roughness height is taller than height of air with zero velocity,than  visocus/skin friction is also pressure drag at microscopic level?

[image]

Comment: Not really. Air particles oscillate because of [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion), and when they hit the surface, they lose speed in the direction opposite to the movement of that surface. This also explains why there is still a shear layer some distance from the surface. You wouldn't argue that air molecules are rough themselves in order to explain that speed gradient, would you?

Comment: @PeterKämpf why then higher surface roughness increase skin friction drag?

Comment: Because there is more surface to bump into. Once the roughness grows beyond the molecular scale, your mechanical model begins to apply.

Comment: @PeterKämpf paint roughness is way beyond molecular level,so basicly my "pressure model"  works in real life all the time..? so its stay unclaer to me,how skin friction really works...